# Logconcavity of height of Dyck paths

Tags: reference-request, co.combinatorics, sequences-and-series

A finite sequence $a_i$ is called logconvace in case $a_i^2 \geq a_{i-1} a_{i+1}$.

> Question : For a fixed $n$, is the sequence $a_{n,k}$ giving the number of Dyck paths of semilength $n$ having height $k$ logconcave? (see http://oeis.org/A080936)

Comment: A starting point is the product formula $(2k^2+6k+1-3n)(2n)!/((n-k)!(n+k+3)!)$ given in the reference, which is, however, valid only for $(n+1)/2\leq k\leq n$.  Computing $T(n,k-1)T(n,k+1)/T(n,k)^2$ gives you three natural factors, which are all less than $1$.

Comment: I have an idea for a combinatorial approach that I'll just sketch for now.  (1) Given two height $k$ paths, follow the first path until you reach height $k$, then insert the entire second path, and finally complete the first path.  (2) Given a height $k-1$ path and a height $k+1$ path, build the same kind of composite path by interrupting the first at height $k-1$.  Both of these approaches create height $2k$ paths.  Why does (1) generate more?  Or starting from the height $2k$ paths, why are there more ways to split them into two height $k$ paths than heights $k-1$ and $k+1$ paths?

Answer (score 2):

A stronger property than log-concavity, is real-rootedness of $\sum_k t^k a_{n,k}$.
However, for $n=4$, this polynomial is $1 + 7 t + 5 t^2 + t^3$ which is not real-rooted.